# CORS (Access Control Allow Origin) on Apache Proxy issue

Tags: apache, proxy, cors, mod-proxy, mod-headers

I need to send a CORS header from my map server (QGIS mapserver) that use a fast cgi with Apache 2.4.* on the port 8080.

I configured the with a simple

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
   [...]
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</VirtualHost>
```

and it works.

I want to set a proxy to avoid the specification of the port in the URL.
I have configured another Virtualhost in the port 80:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPass /cgi-bin/ http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse /cgi-bin/ http://localhost:8080/

    # Is useful this?
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</VirtualHost>
```

but the header is not propagated.
There is a solution?

Answer (score 9):

Add `always`

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"
```

And, enable  headers module

```
a2enmod headers
```

Comment: it is not obvious that a2enmod is installed on the server. better to refer to conf files

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me - using [LocationMatch](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#locationmatch) with ProxyPass and Header set:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  <LocationMatch "/cgi-bin/">
    ProxyPass http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8080/

    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </LocationMatch>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I used <Location> instead of <LocationMatch> but it worked all the same!